# Could this be any other geographic coordinate system than DMS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, google-maps

I got given these coordinates for a point at Erdington Rugby Club, Birmingham. However, when I type them into Google Maps I get an error message and when I convert them from DMS or DDM to DD I end up somewhere completely different.  I just want to check if I'm not missing anything obvious. Is there another coordinate notation system it could be? Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

The coordinates are:

```
latitude 52 31.196 longitude 1 49.770
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct coordinates in decimal degrees (DD) are: [`52.519933 -1.8295`](https://osm.org/go/euzPCf5aS?m=)

The format you provided is Degrees Decimal Minutes (DDM) - see here to convert: https://www.pgc.umn.edu/apps/convert/. Longitude is `1 49.770` **west** (as you know that Birmingham is west of Greenwich meridian), thus negative values - be sure to get that right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You're 100% right that I missed off the minus when I used a DDM converter. Had to be something simple :)